# How to add more data in stapel.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using http://tympanus.net/Development/Stapel. Problem is that on first page they only display name of image gallery and number of images in that gallery. How can i pass other information with .data ? Any suggestion ?

```
<li data-pile="Bryan Moats">
 <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="{{asset('/assetsfront/images/1/2.jpg')}}">
  <span class="tp-info">Test your flu</span>
   <img src="{{asset('/assetsfront/images/1/2.jpg')}}" alt="" />                                
 </a>
</li>
```

They use data-pile so i want to add more data like data-date and data-location.